# how to use EOF with fgets() in C

Tags: c, input, stdin, fgets

I'm trying to read in inputs from the terminal, I want to stop reading inputs if there is a blank line and enter is pressed. Here is what I have at the moment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

   int main(int argc,char const *argv[]){
       char input[1024];

       while(fgets(input,1024,stdin)!=NULL){
          printf("%s", input);
       }
       if(EOF){
          printf("EOF");
       }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code will *always* print `"EOF"`, since `EOF` is, per the standard, non-zero and fixed. Checking for an empty line (single newline only) is trivial. `while(fgets(input,1024,stdin)!=NULL && *input != '\n')` , but that won't solve your issue following the while-loop.

Comment: Look up what `fgets` returns on success and end-of-file. It is really well documented behavior.

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen someone try `if(EOF)` before ... congratulations on finding something new to try in C

Comment: When you don't use command line arguments in the program, the appropriate form for the definition of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Comment: Where you have `if (EOF)` is, interestingly, one of the few places where it might be appropriate to use `feof()` instead: `if (feof(stdin)) printf("EOF\n"); else if (ferror(stdin)) printf("ERR\n"); else assert("can't happen" == 0);` would be correct.  Beware though: [Why is `while (!feof(file))` always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy thing that you could do is to check the length of the string read in by `fgets`.  The newline character at the end of the input string is considered a valid character by `fgets`.  That means that the length of the string you're testing would be 1 if you just entered a newline  So, you want to move the test inside the loop instead of trying to test for EOF outside of the loop.  So, your code should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char input[1024];

    while(fgets(input,1024,stdin)!=NULL) {
        printf("%s", input);
        if(strlen(input) == 1) {
            printf("EOF\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also note, to get the EOF test to work you wouldn't hit enter, instead you'd send the end of file key, like CTRL-D on linux to your program.  In this case you wouldn't have a strlen test inside the loop.